# give shop manager access to appearance wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to **allow** the "shop manager" to access to Appearance to edit Menu, how can I do that, I mean which code shall I add to *function.php*

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should add "Edit Theme Options" which includes manage menu to the role "shop manager"

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Comment: Indeed I want only to give him hand to Menus and Widgets only, if you can help!

Comment: Put the above in your functions.php

Comment: Thanks man! it worked very well now I want to display in the sub menu only Menus and Widgets, do you have any idea how to do that?!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/allow-editors-to-edit-menus

you can also display certain menu under Apperance.

Hope this helps.

```
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

You can comment out this entire code after you have refreshed your admin panel, because the above code will make persistent changes to the database.

You now have all the options under appearance visible to the editors. You can hide the other options like so:

```
function hide_menu() {

    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' ); // hide the theme selection submenu
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' ); // hide the widgets submenu

    // these are theme-specific. Can have other names or simply not exist in your current theme.
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'yiw_panel' );
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'custom-header' );
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'custom-background' );
}
```

add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menu');
The last 3 lines in the hide_menu() function are theme specific for my theme. You can find the second parameter by clicking on the submenu you want to hide, in the admin panel. Your URL will then be something like: example.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=yiw_panel

So, in this example, the second parameter for the remove_submenu_page() function will be yiw_panel

Answer (score 0):

To hide Woocommerce submenus under the top-level menu "Products" for all Shop Manager user roles (Wordpress 5.1.1):

```
function remove_menus_shopmgr(){

// If the current user is a shop manager
if ( current_user_can('shop_manager') ) {

   //removes Products > Categories submenu 
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product','edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&amp;post_type=product' );

   //removes Products > Tags submenu
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product','edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_tag&amp;post_type=product' ); 

    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus_shopmgr', 999 );
```